# facebook app links not working on my Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk, intentfilter

I am trying to put facebook app links in my app because I want when someone opens a path like this

> www.example.com/users/userid

I get the user id in my Android app and I did that but it is still not working in my `index.html` which should be in `www.example.com`

this is the html prefix

> http://ogp.me/ns#">

and the tags are

```
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="example://users/*">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.example.example">
    <meta property="al:android:class" content="com.example.example.Activities.UserActivity">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="example">


<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />

<meta property="og:title" content="example" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

and the activity that I want to open is **UserActivity**
and this is what in my **Manifest.xml**

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


            <data android:scheme="example" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and it gives me null. So what could the problem?